# How to set app name different with name of app shortcut android

Tags: android

I have a android application, I want to set the app shortcut name to "Title1" and the app name elsewhere (for instance on home page or within the app screens) should be "Title2".
How can I do that? Any example?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `AndroidManifest` you can set the `Application` name independently from the `Activity` titles. For example

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:title="@string/activity_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I did that, App will set name is value of "@string/activity_name", but when I long press in icon app to create a shortcut in home launcher of android, the name of shortcut using the name of activity (MainActivity above) too.
Any way to they different?

Comment: So you want the name of the app in the app list to be different from the name on the home screen?

Comment: Yes, @TheoKanning. Can you help me, please?

Comment: As far as I know, Android uses the same information to get the name in the list and homescreen, so there's no way to define a separate name

Answer (score 1):

```
private void addShortcut() { 
//Adding shortcut for MainActivity on Home screen 
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher));

addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Change string value "app_name" when you create shortcut. It will change app shortcut name precisely.

Comment: Thanks!  But I long press in icon app to create a shortcut in home launcher of android, the name of shortcut still do not change. any way?